# Teamcity web-interface does not work

Tags: windows, teamcity

I have Teamcity on Windows machine.
When installed it, I selected the 8080 port.
I have another application on the 80 and 443 ports.
It worked fine, but now I see an error:

[image]

But if I open `localhost:8080` on a virtual machine - all works well.

1. What happened? Maybe you know :(
2. How I can change port or change working to "without SSL"?
3. How I can move all my projects to another Teamcity?

Thanks!

Comment: for your 2) just use http:// instead of https:// (which is likely your problem)

Comment: @Tensibai it is not working. Auto redirect to https http://nuget.b2bfamily.com:8080/

Comment: Then sorry, but the message being what it is, the SSL configuration (either the certificate or the listener configuration, or whatever to be guessed somewhere in your installation) is invalid. May worth trying with another browser, but I'm unsure this would change the result.

Comment: I agree with @Tensibai, you probably have to use non-HTTPs. You're on Firefox; it and Chrome auto redirect to HTTPS. I have to use Vivaldi for projects I know aren't configured with SSL

Comment: Thaks for all answers. Teamcity work correctly when I installed windows updates. Maybe it depended with last microsoft security update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thaks for all answers. 
Teamcity began to work correctly when I installed all windows updates to my Windows Server 2012 R2. 
Maybe it depended with last Microsoft security update.